# Using diodes to supply current

Tags: power

I have connected a 6a silicon diode to my psu and i supply 12v dc current trough that diode to my car audio head unit,But why is this diode is over heating? please anyone answer me.

Comment: How much current does your audio unit draw? What do you mean by overheating? What does the datasheet of the diode say ( a link to the datasheet would be nice)?

Answer (score 2):

The diode may be supplying an average current of (say) 2 amps and might be dropping up to 1 volt across its terminals in doing so. This dissipates 2 watts of power and, of course the diode will produce 2 watts of heat. If you check the diode's data sheet it will have a number that tells you what the temperature rise is per watt. Based on that number, and the watts dissipated, will determine whether some form of heat sinking is required.